# Color scheme not applied in iTerm2 

Tags: mac, terminal, iterm, iterm2

I haven't been able to apply **any** color scheme to iTerm2.

It looks like that the Basic Colors are applied, but the ANSI Colors are not (as shown in Preferences>Profiles>Colors).

Using Mac OSX 10.7.2. Any help?

Comment: So there is a bug in iterm2.... Use default item provided....

Comment: Really *any* color you select? What is the *Terminal Type* selected in *Preferences » Profiles » Default » Terminal* under *Terminal Emulation*?

Comment: @slhck Report Terminal Type: **xterm-256color**

Comment: Try changing it to `xterm` and see if that works.

Comment: @slhck Changed to `xterm` and `xterm-new` and restarted. Nothing works.

Comment: i just revisited this on 2/3/17 see this link: http://superuser.com/questions/1171515/iterm-color-scheme-profile-command/1174651#1174651

Answer (score 108, accepted):

I've been having the same issue and this is what seems to have solved it:

In your .bash_profile set CLICOLOR before setting TERM:

```
# Set CLICOLOR if you want Ansi Colors in iTerm2 
export CLICOLOR=1

# Set colors to match iTerm2 Terminal Colors
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

save bash file and source:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Then, in your iTerm2 Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Report Terminal Type, set to either xterm-256color or xterm

Close iTerm2, restart it and type ls. That did the trick for me.

Good luck.

---

### Catalina and ZSH

If using ZSH, which is the default shell in Catalina and later, use `~/.zprofile`, instead of `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: it works very well for me

Comment: exporting the CLICOLOR finally made colors appear in iTerm2. The preference had xterm-256color set, I wonder why this was tripping it up.

Comment: if this doesn't work, that a look at the 2nd answer bellow about the contrast...

Comment: thanks so much - first time in my life I solved an issue after giving up - I started doing something else and then saw this answer out the corner of my eye, decided to give it one last go and BOOM - thanks again

Comment: I also have to change my color preset, for me `Solarized Dark` didn't work but `Dark background` worked. `Preferences -> Profiles - > Colors -> Color presets`

Answer (score 44):

this is a really old question, but make sure your `Preferences -> Profiles -> Colors -> Minimum contrast` setting is not at the max... if it is and you've done what is suggested above, slide it to a lower setting and you should see the colors appear.

Comment: Works great, but it's Preferences > Profiles > Colors > Minimum Contrast

Comment: You're a life saver. iterm has to many damn options.

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and [found a solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iterm2-discuss/eMow1LBQPH0): 
`Profiles -> Colors -> Minimum Contrast`. If it's high, then you only get black and white.

Comment: i set this without knowing that it set all the colors to black & white, and this comment help me fix that. THanks!

Comment: superb! it worked, what a ...flower! ... my iterm got setup like that by default.

Comment: Perfect! I slide everything back to 0 and everything is colored again. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `zsh` and @sam3k answer didn't work for you - you should put those lines in `.zshrc` instead of `.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Several answers have mentioned the contrast setting. Even at about 60% of the way across my ANSI blue turned black.

Crank the contrast down before you look for other solutions; it is way more aggressive than I expected.

Answer (score 0):

If both modifying .zshrc and turning down minimum contrast DIDN'T WORK, then also make sure that Cursor Boost value is small enough.

Answer (score 0):

Added:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

To the following file:

```
~/.zshrc
```

I saved this and then I ran:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

The color scheme was then applied.

Please not you will need to run the source command for every terminal window that was already open before you made the changes in the .zshrc file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but had to change a Mac OS Preference for the color scheme to be persisted.

Opening 'System Preferences' and unchecking the 'Close windows when quitting an app' radio button worked for me.