# Bash does not recognize color codes and escapes

Tags: bash, colors, color-profiles

I am on iTerm2 on mac, and my shell is Bash. I have the following settings. 
Bash does not recognize the colorcode and escapes.

```
$export CLICOLOR=1
$echo $TERM
xterm-256color
$echo -e "\e[31mHello World\e[0m"
\e[31mHello World\e[0m
$
```

Any suggestions on how do I fix this?

Comment: Related: [Color scheme not applied in iTerm2](http://superuser.com/q/399594/87805) at SU

Comment: @kenorb, I tried those instructions. It did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `\033` instead of `\e`:

```
echo -e "\033[31mHello World\033[0m"
```

Help from: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/colorizing.html