# iTerm2 color scheme not working

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, colors, iterm2

I have trouble setting up colors for iTerm2. I have already checked this answer and done everything it says:

[Color scheme not applied in iTerm2](https://superuser.com/questions/399594/color-scheme-not-applied-in-iterm2)

But iTerm2 does not show any colour, besides white font and dark background. On the other hand, the mac os x terminal app works perfectly. I already make iTerm my default terminal.

I'm using Mac Os X 10.9.5, recently updated from Snow Leopard. Thanks for helping